# Java swing Rendering Issue

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java programming. I created a simple Notepad using swing in Windows 7. It was working fine there. Later I moved it to Windows 8 and now I got some rendering issue. The frames are not rendering properly as shown below.

Here is my Code:

```
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class SpellChecker extends JFrame {

    JTextArea txtrEditorpane = new JTextArea();
    Boolean fileSaved = false,fileEdited=false;
    String savedFileNAme = "";


    public SpellChecker() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                if(fileEdited){
                    int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous File First?","Unsaved Changes",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        saveFile();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setTitle("Untitled.txt");

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        mntmNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(fileEdited){
                    int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous File First?","Unsaved Changes",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        saveFile();
                    }
                }
                setTitle("Untitled.txt");
                txtrEditorpane.setText("");
            }
        });
        mnFile.add(mntmNew);

        JMenuItem mntmOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
        mntmOpen.addActionListener(new OpenL());
        mnFile.add(mntmOpen);

        JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        mntmSave.addActionListener(new SaveL());
        mnFile.add(mntmSave);

        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(fileEdited){
                    int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous File First?","Unsaved Changes",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        saveFile();
                    }
                }
                SpellChecker.this.dispose();
            }
        });
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);

        JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(mnEdit);

        JMenuItem mntmFont = new JMenuItem("Font");
        mntmFont.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFontChooser fontChooser = new JFontChooser();
                   int result = fontChooser.showDialog(SpellChecker.this);
                   if (result == JFontChooser.OK_OPTION)
                   {
                        Font font = fontChooser.getSelectedFont(); 
                        txtrEditorpane.setFont(font);
                   }
            }
        });
        mnEdit.add(mntmFont);

        JMenuItem mntmForecolor = new JMenuItem("ForeColor");
        mntmForecolor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Color initialcolor=txtrEditorpane.getForeground();  
                Color color=JColorChooser.showDialog(SpellChecker.this,"Select a color",initialcolor);  
                txtrEditorpane.setForeground(color);
            }
        });
        mnEdit.add(mntmForecolor);

        JMenuItem mntmBackgroundColor = new JMenuItem("BackGround Color");
        mntmBackgroundColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Color initialcolor=txtrEditorpane.getBackground();  
                Color color=JColorChooser.showDialog(SpellChecker.this,"Select a color",initialcolor);  
                txtrEditorpane.setBackground(color);
            }
        });
        mnEdit.add(mntmBackgroundColor);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);

        JMenuItem mntmAboutUs = new JMenuItem("About Us");
        mnHelp.add(mntmAboutUs);
        txtrEditorpane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if(fileSaved){
                    SpellChecker.this.setTitle(savedFileNAme+"*");
                    fileEdited=true;
                }
                else {
                    SpellChecker.this.setTitle("Untitled.txt*");
                    fileEdited=true;
                }
            }
        });
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(txtrEditorpane);
        getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);

    }

    class SaveL implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveFile();
        }
    }

    public void saveFile() {
        String filename, dir;
        FileWriter fw = null;       
        if (fileSaved) {                        
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(savedFileNAme);
                fw.write(txtrEditorpane.getText());
            } catch (Exception err) {

            } finally {
                try {
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
            FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text file",
                    new String[] { "txt" });
            c.setFileFilter(filter);
            c.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            // Demonstrate "Save" dialog:
            int rVal = c.showSaveDialog(SpellChecker.this);
            if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                filename = c.getSelectedFile().getName();
                dir = c.getCurrentDirectory().toString();                   
                savedFileNAme = dir + "\\" + filename + ".txt";
                try {
                    fw = new FileWriter(savedFileNAme);
                    fw.write(txtrEditorpane.getText());
                } catch (Exception err) {

                } finally {
                    try {
                        fw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                fileSaved = true;
                fileEdited=false;
            }
            if (rVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                // Do on Cancel
            }

        }
        SpellChecker.this.setTitle(savedFileNAme);
    }
    class OpenL implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
            FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text file",
                    new String[] { "txt" });
            c.setFileFilter(filter);
            c.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            String filename, dir;
            // File "Open" dialog:
            int rVal = c.showOpenDialog(SpellChecker.this);
            if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                filename = c.getSelectedFile().getName();
                dir = c.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
                savedFileNAme = dir + "\\" + filename ;
                try {
                    String text = new Scanner(new File(savedFileNAme))
                            .useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                    txtrEditorpane.setText(text);
                } catch (Exception err) {

                } finally {

                }
                SpellChecker.this.setTitle(savedFileNAme);
                fileSaved=true;

            }
            if (rVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                // filename.setText("You pressed cancel");
                // dir.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the problem (Windows 8):

[image: Unexpected Swing behavior on Windows 8]

I am using Java 8. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to include a screenshot?  That might help you get answers more quickly.

Comment: Yes but i am unable to add screenshot since i am new to StackExchange :-(

Comment: Is there a way to Add Screen Shot for new user?

Comment: Post a link from a photo hosting site.

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/81bqztfxh/GUIScreen.png

Comment: Care to post a screenshot of the expected behavior (what you're seeing on Windows 7) too?

Comment: Did you try executing your code without the javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); call. This could have an impact, especially if it works fine in Windows 7 and you didn't change anything.

Comment: Dont have Screens for win 7 now . but it was like a normal Menu.

Comment: Yes tried without javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()) but same effect...

Answer (score 0):

I've also ran into a Swing rendering issue. The HelloWorld Java 8 application that worked fine on MAC didn't work on Windows 7. The problem was with the video drivers on Windows.

Details here: http://yakovfain.com/2014/06/27/swing-rendering-seems-to-be-broken-in-java-8/